# gapi.analytics.ext undefined error while implementing google third-party visualisations

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I have implemented the code as described in the google documentation:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations

The scripts were not loading so i called them in jquery inside script tags.

If any other way to implement this please tell me.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demo</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->
<header>
  <div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
  <div id="view-selector-container"></div>
  <div id="view-name"></div>
  <div id="active-users-container"></div>
</header>
<div class="Chartjs">
  <h3>This Week vs Last Week (by sessions)</h3>
  <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-1-container"></figure>
  <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-1-container"></ol>
</div>
<div class="Chartjs">
  <h3>This Year vs Last Year (by users)</h3>
  <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-2-container"></figure>
  <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-2-container"></ol>
</div>
<div class="Chartjs">
  <h3>Top Browsers (by pageview)</h3>
  <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-3-container"></figure>
  <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-3-container"></ol>
</div>
<div class="Chartjs">
  <h3>Top Countries (by sessions)</h3>
  <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-4-container"></figure>
  <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-4-container"></ol>
</div>

<script>
  (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
    g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
    js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
  }(window,document,'script'));
  $(function(){
   $.getScript( "https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/components/view-selector2.js" );
   $.getScript( "https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/components/date-range-selector.js" );
   $.getScript( "https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/components/active-users.js" );

  gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
    // $.getScript( "/assets/javascripts/active-users.js" );
    //$.getScript( "/assets/javascripts/active-users.js" );
    /**
     * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
     * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
     * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
     */
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
      container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
      clientid: '517272899128-6pmdujph12oo75hbq4d2bpqsh34bthah.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    });


    /**
     * Create a new ActiveUsers instance to be rendered inside of an
     * element with the id "active-users-container" and poll for changes every
     * five seconds.
     */
    var activeUsers = new gapi.analytics.ext.ActiveUsers({
      container: 'active-users-container',
      pollingInterval: 5
    });


    /**
     * Add CSS animation to visually show the when users come and go.
     */
    activeUsers.once('success', function() {
      var element = this.container.firstChild;
      var timeout;

      this.on('change', function(data) {
        var element = this.container.firstChild;
        var animationClass = data.delta > 0 ? 'is-increasing' : 'is-decreasing';
        element.className += (' ' + animationClass);

        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          element.className =
              element.className.replace(/ is-(increasing|decreasing)/g, '');
        }, 3000);
      });
    });


    /**
     * Create a new ViewSelector2 instance to be rendered inside of an
     * element with the id "view-selector-container".
     */
    var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
      container: 'view-selector-container',
    })
    .execute();


    /**
     * Update the activeUsers component, the Chartjs charts, and the dashboard
     * title whenever the user changes the view.
     */
    viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {
      var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
      title.textContent = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';

      // Start tracking active users for this view.
      activeUsers.set(data).execute();

      // Render all the of charts for this view.
      renderWeekOverWeekChart(data.ids);
      renderYearOverYearChart(data.ids);
      renderTopBrowsersChart(data.ids);
      renderTopCountriesChart(data.ids);
    });


    /**
     * Draw the a chart.js line chart with data from the specified view that
     * overlays session data for the current week over session data for the
     * previous week.
     */
    function renderWeekOverWeekChart(ids) {

      // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
      var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

      var thisWeek = query({
        'ids': ids,
        'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
        'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
        'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      });

      var lastWeek = query({
        'ids': ids,
        'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
        'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
        'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).subtract(1, 'week')
            .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        'end-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(6).subtract(1, 'week')
            .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      });

      Promise.all([thisWeek, lastWeek]).then(function(results) {

        var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
        var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
        var labels = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[0]; });

        labels = labels.map(function(label) {
          return moment(label, 'YYYYMMDD').format('ddd');
        });

        var data = {
          labels : labels,
          datasets : [
            {
              label: 'Last Week',
              fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
              strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
              pointColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
              pointStrokeColor : '#fff',
              data : data2
            },
            {
              label: 'This Week',
              fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
              strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
              pointColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
              pointStrokeColor : '#fff',
              data : data1
            }
          ]
        };

        new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-1-container')).Line(data);
        generateLegend('legend-1-container', data.datasets);
      });
    }


    /**
     * Draw the a chart.js bar chart with data from the specified view that
     * overlays session data for the current year over session data for the
     * previous year, grouped by month.
     */
    function renderYearOverYearChart(ids) {

      // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
      var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

      var thisYear = query({
        'ids': ids,
        'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
        'metrics': 'ga:users',
        'start-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      });

      var lastYear = query({
        'ids': ids,
        'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
        'metrics': 'ga:users',
        'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'year').date(1).month(0)
            .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        'end-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).subtract(1, 'day')
            .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      });

      Promise.all([thisYear, lastYear]).then(function(results) {
        var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
        var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
        var labels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                      'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

        // Ensure the data arrays are at least as long as the labels array.
        // Chart.js bar charts don't (yet) accept sparse datasets.
        for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
          if (data1[i] === undefined) data1[i] = null;
          if (data2[i] === undefined) data2[i] = null;
        }

        var data = {
          labels : labels,
          datasets : [
            {
              label: 'Last Year',
              fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
              strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
              data : data2
            },
            {
              label: 'This Year',
              fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
              strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
              data : data1
            }
          ]
        };

        new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-2-container')).Bar(data);
        generateLegend('legend-2-container', data.datasets);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
      });
    }


    /**
     * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
     * show the top 5 browsers over the past seven days.
     */
    function renderTopBrowsersChart(ids) {

      query({
        'ids': ids,
        'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
        'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
        'max-results': 5
      })
      .then(function(response) {

        var data = [];
        var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

        response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
          data.push({ value: +row[1], color: colors[i], label: row[0] });
        });

        new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-3-container')).Doughnut(data);
        generateLegend('legend-3-container', data);
      });
    }


    /**
     * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
     * compares sessions from mobile, desktop, and tablet over the past seven
     * days.
     */
    function renderTopCountriesChart(ids) {
      query({
        'ids': ids,
        'dimensions': 'ga:country',
        'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
        'sort': '-ga:sessions',
        'max-results': 5
      })
      .then(function(response) {

        var data = [];
        var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

        response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
          data.push({
            label: row[0],
            value: +row[1],
            color: colors[i]
          });
        });

        new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-4-container')).Doughnut(data);
        generateLegend('legend-4-container', data);
      });
    }


    /**
     * Extend the Embed APIs `gapi.analytics.report.Data` component to
     * return a promise the is fulfilled with the value returned by the API.
     * @param {Object} params The request parameters.
     * @return {Promise} A promise.
     */
    function query(params) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({query: params});
        data.once('success', function(response) { resolve(response); })
            .once('error', function(response) { reject(response); })
            .execute();
      });
    }


    /**
     * Create a new canvas inside the specified element. Set it to be the width
     * and height of its container.
     * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the canvas.
     * @return {RenderingContext} The 2D canvas context.
     */
    function makeCanvas(id) {
      var container = document.getElementById(id);
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      container.innerHTML = '';
      canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
      canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;
      container.appendChild(canvas);

      return ctx;
    }


    /**
     * Create a visual legend inside the specified element based off of a
     * Chart.js dataset.
     * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the legend.
     * @param {Array.<Object>} items A list of labels and colors for the legend.
     */
    function generateLegend(id, items) {
      var legend = document.getElementById(id);
      legend.innerHTML = items.map(function(item) {
        var color = item.color || item.fillColor;
        var label = item.label;
        return '<li><i style="background:' + color + '"></i>' +
            escapeHtml(label) + '</li>';
      }).join('');
    }


    // Set some global Chart.js defaults.
    Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 60;
    Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = 'easeInOutQuart';
    Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
    Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;


    /**
     * Escapes a potentially unsafe HTML string.
     * @param {string} str An string that may contain HTML entities.
     * @return {string} The HTML-escaped string.
     */
    function escapeHtml(str) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
      return div.innerHTML;
    }

  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the scripts are not loading so this error might be coming.
I tried to load the scripts directly and as specified in the documentation but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Please provide your code with proper comments, it will help in understanding your problem

Comment: Not sure if that just an omission in your example, but wouldn't the use of $.getScript require jQuery to be loaded ?